# Flash Builder no longer starts

Tags: flash-builder

Good old Flash builder. It no longer starts now. After multiple reinstalls I'm stuck. Adobe aren't helping so I'm at the end of my tether. Here's the log:

```
!SESSION 2012-07-19 22:04:01.466 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20100608-0911
java.version=1.6.0_33
java.vendor=Apple Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/ahmed/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86 -keyring /Users/ahmed/.eclipse_keyring -consoleLog -showlocation

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine 4 4 2012-07-19 22:04:19.445
!MESSAGE An error occurred while committing the engine session for profile: epp.package.java.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.eclipse 4 0 2012-07-19 22:04:19.445
!MESSAGE 
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.eclipse 4 0 2012-07-19 22:04:19.445
!MESSAGE Error saving manipulator.
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.frameworkadmin.equinox.EquinoxFwConfigFileParser.saveFwConfig(EquinoxFwConfigFileParser.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.frameworkadmin.equinox.EquinoxManipulatorImpl.save(EquinoxManipulatorImpl.java:407)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.LazyManipulator.save(LazyManipulator.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.EclipseTouchpoint.saveManipulator(EclipseTouchpoint.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.EclipseTouchpoint.commit(EclipseTouchpoint.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.EngineSession.commit(EngineSession.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.ProfileSynchronizer.executePlan(ProfileSynchronizer.java:768)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.ProfileSynchronizer.performAddRemove(ProfileSynchronizer.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.ProfileSynchronizer.synchronize(ProfileSynchronizer.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.synchronize(Activator.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.start(Activator.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2012-07-19 22:04:20.888
!MESSAGE Warnings while parsing the commands from the 'org.eclipse.ui.commands' and 'org.eclipse.ui.actionDefinitions' extension points.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2012-07-19 22:04:20.889
!MESSAGE Commands should really have a category: plug-in='com.qnx.flashbuilder.multiplatform.qnx.ui', id='com.qnx.flashbuilder.multiplatform.qnx.ui.commands.OpenInfoCenter', categoryId='com.qnx.flashbuilder.multiplatform.qnx.ui.commands.category.help'

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2012-07-19 22:04:23.363
!MESSAGE System property http.nonProxyHosts has been set to local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16 by an external source. This value will be overwritten using the values from the preferences
```

I'm not too sure why there's this `Error saving manipulator` problem, silly Flash Builder!

Comment: Did you try deleting the metadata folder your workspace? That usually works for me when FB won't start any more.

Comment: Darn. My last tip then is to remove FB completely (using the Adobe removal tool followed by an app removal tool (e.g. appcleaner)) and install it again, if you haven't already tried that.

Comment: I've got AppZapper but once the Adobe manager has removed it I can't see what else I can try and get rid off. Prefs and caches have been cleared.

Comment: Ok last clue then, when did you update your Java version? I'm still on 1.6.0_31. Maybe the "new" (june 12th) _33 broke something. A re-install of Java could fix the issue. If not and no one else can help you, try the Adobe support again.

Comment: I'm on Mac and I can't remember a software update recently that included a new Java version. It just suddenly stopped, which is very annoying.